# Unable to retrieve GridFS files from MongoDB after restore

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I have a MongoDB that is +-60GB that I have restored locally.  When I try to retrieve files from the database using GridFS I can get a list of the files but when I call GridFS.DownloadAsBytes(objectId) the code never returns.

I have tried the same thing using mongofiles. I can list the files but when I try to get a file by name mongofiles just hangs / doesn't return. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the reasons to why this worked but I had MongoDB 3.6 installed but our current server installation is using MongoDB 3.4 after downgrading to MongoDB 3.4 the files are now downloading super quickly.